# How to add the words in a new page while adding images and words in itext

Tags: java, itext

I need to add some groups of images to pdf by itext5，and separate different groups with 
words.I hope every group of images beginning in a new page,my code is like this:

```java
        Document document = new Document();
        byte[] imageA1 = .......;
        byte[] imageA2 = .......;
        byte[] imageA3 = .......;
        byte[] imageA4 = .......;
        byte[] imageB1 = .......;
        byte[] imageB2 = .......;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, bos);
            document.open();
            document.newPage();
            document.add(new Paragraph("(This is groupA"));
            document.add(Image.getInstance(imageA1));
            document.add(Image.getInstance(imageA2));
            document.add(Image.getInstance(imageA3));
            document.add(Image.getInstance(imageA4));
            document.newPage();
            document.add(new Paragraph("(This is groupB"));
            document.add(Image.getInstance(imageB1));
            document.add(Image.getInstance(imageB2));
            document.close();
            byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
```

However，they were priented one by one, the words weren't added to a new page:

[image: the wrong example]

This is what I expect:

[image: the right example]

How to solve it?

Comment: I just found if  I invoke documnet.newPage()  twice, it works :)  I don't think it's a right solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In short

This behavior is caused by iText by default treating images as something it can float to the next page if there is not enough space left for the image on the current page. You can override this effect by setting the `StrictImageSequence` property of the `PdfWriter` to `true`. In specific circumstances your double `newPage` also does the job.

## In detail

#### Floating images in iText

When adding an image to a page, iText first checks whether there is enough space left on the page for the image. If there is not, iText by default not immediately starts a new page to put the image on but instead merely stores the image in a local variable. When eventually a new page is created for some other reason, e.g. by adding enough text to invoke the page switch or by calling `newPage()` explicitly, the stored image is immediately added to the new page as first content.

This prevents mostly empty pages in case of a mixture of huge images and text.

Beware, as there is only a single image variable for this, adding yet another non-fitting image will trigger the generation of a new page and drawing of the first waiting image nonetheless.

#### Your original case

In case of your output

[image: OP's screenshot]

the image at top was added to the document when the previous page was still current. It didn't fit, so it was stored in a variable. Then your explicit `newPage()` call created a new page and the image from the variable was added as first content on that new page, and only thereafter your "(This is group B)" which you wanted to be the first content, was drawn.

#### Your work-around

In case of your work-around

> if I invoke documnet.newPage() twice, it works

yet another new page is generated after the image is drawn in the course of the first `newPage()` call.

On the other hand, if there is no stored image for the new page, the second `newPage()` is ignored because iText by default suppresses empty pages.

Thus, your work-around might be useful in your very use-case.

#### Disabling floating images in iText

The more general solution, though, would be to suppress floating images in iText completely. You can do so by setting the `PdfWriter` property `StrictImageSequence` to `true`:

```
writer.setStrictImageSequence(true);
```

It might also be the better solution in your case, in particular if you eventually start adding extra text between the images in the same group.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your `iText` version, but I assume you have to create a `PdfDocument` instead of a `Document`.

Comment: The OP uses itext before version 7 (if that code is compiled against itext 7, one gets lots of errors), and in itext before 7 you don't create a `PdfDocument`.

Comment: I use itext 2.1 (I know, really old) and there you create a PdfDocument.

Comment: In 2.1? I doubt it. At least in 2.1.7 `PdfDocument` was used internally only,  and I really doubt the architecture of itext changed so vehemently between 2.1 and 2.1.7.

Comment: I looked again at my code and found that it was in some test code (it's been some years since I had worked with itext pdf). Also I saw that the `PdfWriter` internally creates a `PdfDocument`. So you can directly create a `PdfDocument` and use it with `PdfWriter`.

Comment: Yes, `PdfWriter` *internally* creates a `PdfDocument`, and this is the intended usage. Due to the visibility of `PdfDocument` and its constructor you of course *can* instantiate it yourself but this is *not intended* by the iText developers. My *"in itext before 7 you don't create a `PdfDocument`"* in my first comment here refers to this *usage intended by the iText developers*.